# Got an error from Linux min about Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have installed MongoDB on my Linux meant. I can't figure out the error.

Actually, it is a warning like this

```
W: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/Release.gpg: Signature by key 492EAFE8CD016A07919F1D2B9ECBEC467F0CEB10 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem.

**EDIT:**

I wrote sudo apt-get update in the terminal. I got this warning in the last line on the each update.

Comment: can you elaborate the process you did so that we can find where you got the error. And another did you got just the warning or it through an error, as you have mentioned as just warning in question

Comment: Yes, it is a warning as i said. But i want to solve that also.

Comment: I cant get you.

Comment: elaborate the question like the process or steps you followed for installation or upgradation

Comment: I wrote sudo apt-ge update in terminal. I got this warning in the last line on the each update

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get upgrade` instead of `sudo apt-get update`

To see if any package upgrades are available use 
`sudo apt update` (notice it's just apt) does provide feedback about the results.

By using apt, you will either see a message that

> All packages are up to date

or

> The following packages will be upgraded

Also see `apt list --upgradeable`.